# Entity Framework Table Per Class Inheritance

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement a history table for an entity in EF6, code first.

I figured there would be a way to do this with inheritance. The history table, which is a derived type of the actual table entity, just containing straight copies of all the properties. Along with an edit to the key.

My code first table entity config for `Booking`.

```
public class BookingEntityConfiguration
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<Booking>
{
    public BookingEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Property(b => b.BookingId).HasColumnOrder(0);
        HasKey(b => new { b.BookingId });

        HasOptional(b => b.BookingType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.BookingTypeId);
    }
}
```

My code first table entity config for `BookingHistory`.

```
public class BookingHistoryTypeEntityConfiguration
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<BookingHistory>
{
    public BookingHistoryTypeEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Property(b => b.BookingId).HasColumnOrder(0);
        Property(b => b.BookingVersion).HasColumnOrder(0);
        HasKey(b => new { b.BookingId, b.BookingVersion });
    }
}
```

Where

```
public class BookingHistory : Booking { }
```

My `BookingHistory` table never gets generated in the contexts associated database, which includes these references to the table entities:

```
public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
public DbSet<BookingHistory> BookingHistories { get; set; }
```

Is there any simple way to achieve what I want? Which is the derived entity (history table) generates a table that contains the same column fields as the base class entity, but with a change of key.

I appreciate my code above is pretty naive, but I can't seem to find a blog post of similar to help.

Comment: LOL... thanks? I have read all of these posts, but none of them really help with what I require, or want, it may not be possible of course. But it's always better to hear that from an expert than waste time pulling hairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to have a base type from which both the entity and its history entity inherit:

```
public class BookingsContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookingHistory> BookingHistories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookingBase>()
            .HasKey(p => p.BookingId)
            .Property(p => p.BookingId)
                       .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("Booking");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookingHistory>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("BookingHistory");
            });
    }
}
```

By `ToTable` you specify that both entities should be mapped to different tables. On top of that, `MapInheritedProperties` tells EF to mapp all properties from the base type to this table as well. the result is two completely independent tables that can be addressed by two separate `DbSet` properties.

Comment: OK... So if the history inherits from, say, the booking, it will contain all the same fields and I can set the keys up seperately. I will give this a go.